# Custom Button Positioning

Tags: java, javafx

I decided to create Custom Buttons with Shapes, which are animated. So i followed a tutorial and had everything set up and it worked properly, until i added a few other items to the scene. I saw that the positioning methods i was using on these private Classes were showing right, but behind the scenes the Button had another instance with the absolute values i set in the button class.

To clarify the situation, this is how it looks:

[image]

The ToggleSwitch i build is a Circle in a Rectangle, which moves and changes its background color, once it is clicked

And this is how it reacts:

[image]

Meaning, that it is blocking the upper Buttons

I used the following Code snippet for it:

```
private static class ToggleSwitch extends Parent {

...

public BooleanProperty switchedOnProperty() {
    return switchedOn;
}

public ToggleSwitch() {
    Rectangle background = new Rectangle(102, 52);
    background.setArcWidth(50);
    background.setArcHeight(50);
    background.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    background.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

    Circle trigger = new Circle(25);
    trigger.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    trigger.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

    // These two lines are my problem!!
    trigger.setCenterX(26); 
    trigger.setCenterY(26);
    ...
}
}
```

So i don't know how to set the position of the Circle for it to be in the Rectangle and not have "another instance" blocking my application.

This has to be the problem, since after removing it from the scene everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem wasn't in the creation in of the Buttons, but in the way i added them to a pane.
Since i used only a normal Pane object as root pane to switch between content it all was stuck in the Position (0,0).

Solution: Use BorderPane as root Pane.